# Javascript numbers and NaN

Tags: javascript

I have 'little' problem with javascript numbers and `NaN`.

I'm retrieving one single number via ajax POST method in JSON format.

```
$.post('test.php?a=b', {w: w}, function(json) {
    desktop.height = desktop.height - json.height * 2;
});
```

When I try to multiply it, it gives me NaN.

```
desktop.height = desktop.height - json.height * 2;
NaN
```

JSON IS an object, right? So when I enter this into firebug/chrome console, it gives me int 0, as expected.

```
var a = {}; a.t = 0; a.t * 2;
0
```

Even if I enter this into a console, it still gives me expected 0 int.

```
var a = {}; a.t = "0"; a.t * 2;
0
```

My question is, what's going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: Could you provide a complete test case? One which includes the inputs to your expression.

Comment: What does `console.log([desktop.height, json])` show?

Comment: You'll need to post the JSON involved for anybody to explain this precisely. You can add `console.log()` messages to your callback function to print out `typeof desktop.height` and `typeof json.height`.

Comment: There's no way to know whether `json` is an object. What is `test.php` supposed to return?

Comment: `NaN` happens when one of those numbers isn't a number. Are you sure it's the returned data that's causing it?

Comment: `json` is only an object if (1) the server responds with a valid JSON string and (2) the `Content-Type` header is `application/json`.

Comment: try this (eval(desktop.height) - (json.height))*2

Comment: *"JSON IS an object, right?"* JSON is a data exchange format. The **variable** `json` most likely contains a string.

Comment: @Felix — Unless the server is outputting data with the correct content-type, in which case it will be an Object or an Array.

Comment: @Quentin: Of course, but most people don't set the right headers, that's why I said "most likely". But you are right, we actually don't know. It's just guessing so far.

Comment: PHP code just echos `json_encode(array('height' => 0))`. The input does not matter here at the moment.

Comment: @airmattress — The input does matter. Since that is going to hand jQuery something claiming to be HTML. Add `header("Content-Type: application/json");` if you are outputting JSON.

Comment: @Quentin - Appears, that this was the problem. Adding `'json'` as the 4th parameter in `$.post` method fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Content-Type` header is not set to `application/json` from server and still If you want jQuery to parse the json String into JS object automatically then you have to add `dataType` `json` in `$.post` call.

```
$.post('test.php?a=b', {w: w}, function(json) {
    desktop.height = desktop.height - json.height * 2;
  },'json');
```

or you have to parse that youself using [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) like this

```
  $.post('test.php?a=b', {w: w}, function(json) {
     json = $.parseJSON(json);
     desktop.height = desktop.height - json.height * 2;
  });
```

Comment: No, you don't, not if the content-type of the response is set correctly. You only need to override the data type if the server is broken.

Comment: Adding `'json'` as the 4th parameter fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve you're numbers, parse them using Javascript's `parseInt()` method.

Comment: That shouldn't be needed if the values are numbers in the first place.

Comment: Odd. Let me look at it a bit more.

Comment: @Quentin I've had values that were numbers not parse as integers before, instead parsing as strings. Its just good to at least try that to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the format of the JSON string so if its `{height:<num>}` then yes that is correct. but it could actually be a string, have you tried parsing it as an int first?

```
parseInt(...)
```

Comment: That would only help if it was a string consisting of a number followed by some non-number characters

Answer (score 0):

Either `desktop.height` or `json.height` is `NaN`.

Comment: @airmattress — Really? How did you test it? Or did you look at your PHP and assume that both of the above were numbers?

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a string version of a Javascript object.  Use JSON.parse(text) to create an object from the string recieved from your post.  I am not familar with your post method but I would try

```
function(JSON.parse(json)) {
    desktop.height = desktop.height - json.height * 2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you retrieve you're numbers, parse them using JS **Number()** method :)